# Identify function calls in JS code

Tags: javascript, regex, function, syntax

I need something that can identify function calls in js code. I looked around but didnt find anything... i've come up with a regex: `[a-zA-Z$_]+[a-zA-Z0-9$_]*\(.*\)` But with a function like `ab((foo)/(bar),hello)` this regex breaks. Can this be solved using a regex or do i need to create something parser-like? Sublime text 3 has this implemented in their syntax highlighting and as far as i know they are only using regexes... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I'm getting a full match with the regexp and input you gave. Check [link](https://regex101.com/r/kxR3CY/1)

Comment: I have tried this: [a-zA-Z$_]+[a-zA-Z0-9$_]+(\\(.+\\)|\\(\\))

Comment: You have to use a full JavaScript parser to handle every case of this now, yes.

Comment: For your specified `regex: [a-zA-Z$_]+[a-zA-Z0-9$_]*\(.*\)`

`ab((foo)/(bar),hello)` is a match. Are you sure you did not mean another test? 

Tested on multiple regex testers to make sure. Please check your test string again and provide a failing case.

Comment: im sorry, i provided the rong test case. if you have a brace anywhere in code after the function call, it breaks. Eg. ```foo(bar);foo2()``` will mark ```bar);foo2(``` as arguments to ```foo```